# Getting rows that has max value

Tags: sql, sqlite

For example, my table like that;

```
name   count
----   ----
red      5
green    3
yellow   4
brown    5
purple   2
black    5
```

I want to get a result just like that;

```
name   count
----    ----
black    5
brown    5
red      5
```

So i want the rows that has max count. How can i do that ? 
The MAX() is giving only one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way uses a subquery to find the max value, and then restricts by that max value:

```
SELECT name, count
FROM yourTable
WHERE count = (SELECT MAX(count) FROM yourTable);
```

Depending on your version of SQLite, you may also be able to use analytic functions here.  From the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html):

> Window function support was added to SQLite with release version 3.25.0 (2018-09-15)

If your version supports it, we can try using `RANK`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT name, count, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY count DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT name, count
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select * from tablename
where count=(select max(count) from tablename)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `dense_rank()` window funtion

```
select * from 
(
select *, dense_rank() over(order by count desc) rn from table
) t where t.rn=1
```